# Where are the Spark logs on EMR?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, emr

I'm not able to locate error logs or message's from `println` calls in Scala while running jobs on `Spark` in `EMR`.

Where can I access these?

I'm submitting the `Spark job`, written in `Scala` to `EMR` using `script-runner.jar` with arguments `--deploy-mode` set to `cluster` and `--master` set to `yarn`.  It runs the job fine.

However I do not see my `println` statements in the `Amazon EMR UI` where it lists "stderr, stdout`etc.  Furthermore if my job errors I don't see why it had an error.  All I see is this in the`stderr`:

```
15/05/27 20:24:44 INFO yarn.Client: Application report from ResourceManager: 
 application identifier: application_1432754139536_0002
 appId: 2
 clientToAMToken: null
 appDiagnostics: 
 appMasterHost: ip-10-185-87-217.ec2.internal
 appQueue: default
 appMasterRpcPort: 0
 appStartTime: 1432758272973
 yarnAppState: FINISHED
 distributedFinalState: FAILED
 appTrackingUrl: http://10.150.67.62:9046/proxy/application_1432754139536_0002/A
 appUser: hadoop
```

`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the deploy mode of cluster on yarn the Spark driver and hence the user code executed will be within the Application Master container. It sounds like you had EMR debugging enabled on the cluster so logs should have also pushed to S3. In the S3 location look at `task-attempts/<applicationid>/<firstcontainer>/*`.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  Thank you.  For other users knowledge, you can see this "Log URI" in the Amazon EMR Web UI for your cluster info/details.

Comment: In my case, I  cannot found "task-attempts" when clicking "Log URI" in the EMR Web UI, was it renamed or moved?

Comment: The path to the location for the logs has been changed. Please refer to answer by @Vsh  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62963889/6780081

Answer (score 6):

If you SSH into the master node of your cluster then you should be able to find the stdout, stderr, syslog and controller logs under:

```
/mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/<stepname>
```

Comment: Those are the Step logs, which do not contain the Spark application logs (such as OP's println statements).

Comment: As stated in the above comment, this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

I also spent a lot of time figuring this out. Found logs in the following location:
EMR UI Console -> Summary -> Log URI -> Containers -> application_xxx_xxx -> container_yyy_yy_yy -> stdout.gz.

Comment: Best answer here!

Answer (score 1):

The event logs, the ones required for the `spark-history-server` can be found at :

```
hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
```

Answer (score 0):

If you submit your job with [emr-bootstrap](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/blob/master/spark/examples/spark-submit-via-step.md) you can specify the log directory as an s3 bucket with `--log-uri`

Comment: thanks - I think this might be set when I create the cluster (not when submitting a job)? i'll try next time I create the cluster

Comment: The S3 logs are plain text, however in Spark History Server I can download JSON logs which are prefect for indexing in Elasticsearch (Download button under Event Log column). Where are these stored?